# opencv not able to run some advanced image processing code

Tags: opencv

i am using visual studio 15 
some basic blurring and filters are running perfectly but on some codes such as blending and dct techniques are not running 
Can anyone please help me

Comment: what kind of error do you get? we can't offer a solution to you if you don't tell what your problem is. can you post non working code

Comment: cv array op nor scalar

Comment: unable to getfontdata from cv font

Comment: so what is the error shown in the console?

Comment: c:/builds /masters_packslave-wun64-vc12- shared opencv/modules/improc/src/drawing.cpp 2037 error:-211 unknown font in type in function cv:: getfontdata

Comment: c/builds/master_packslave_win 64-vc12 -shared /opencv/modules/ improc/drawing.cpp 2037 error::-211 unknown font type function cv::getfontdata

Comment: Please avoid to ask multiple (bad) question. Add the code that isn't working, the error you get, and the vs included libraries

Comment: Btw, you're linking with opencv built for with vc12 ( visual studio 2013). You need to link to vc14 (visual studio 2015) libs

Comment: that too also tried but normal code itself not running in vc14

Answer (score 0):

At this point its probably best to create your own compiled library tools for MicroSoft Visual Studio 15.  Here's a [how to guide.](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/) That guide covers all the steps and starts with the most current code on Github.

Also note there are many tutorials out there on OpenCV. Many parts of the OpenCV library have been update, or replaced.  You have to be careful that the commands you are using are valid in OpenCV 3.x

Compile your own, run a few simple programs.

If you want specific help here, you MUST post your code, and the errors you are seeing.